# how to find number with most divisor from array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I got some problem someone of with really helped me but I got program source code who print all of divisor from array, but I tried to print a number with most divisor for ex. array[1,2,3,4,5] and I want to print that the number with most divisor is 4 (1,2,4)

```
public static class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getNumWithMaxDivisors(numbers));
    }

    static int getNumDivisors(int n) {
        int noOfDivisors = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                noOfDivisors++;
            }
        }
        return noOfDivisors;
    }

    static int getNumWithMaxDivisors(int[] numbers) {
        int currentMaxDivisors = 0;
        int numWithMaxDivisors = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int numDivisors = getNumDivisors(numbers[i]);
            if (numDivisors > currentMaxDivisors) {
                numWithMaxDivisors = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return numWithMaxDivisors;
    }
}
```

Code looks that, do you know where is a problem ?

Comment: For the future: please see [mcve], always include expected and **actual** output of your code. And hint: the real answer is: when you dont understand what your code is doing ... just add more print statements. Ideally, first do the whole thing on paper with a pen and a small example. Write down how your variables contain, and so on. The thing with learning programming: figuring "what is my code doing" is really a big part of that. Don't delegate that work easily to other people.

Comment: Okay, i will remeber that, so next time i have to write line by line what i want to do, and what i expect from the code

Comment: Just for clarity: that isn't something you want to do forever. But the key point is that you have to train to "think" like the computer. In coding, every detail matters. Writing code is less than half of the work; the real challenge is to figure "why isn't it doing what I want it to do". And note: as soon as you have a feeling how these computations and loops and methods and all come together ... you switch from paper/pen to ... using a **debugger**, so you can look at your code and the data it is working with right when it is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that inside of your `getNumWithMaxDivisors()` method, you are not redefining the current number of max divisors. To fix this, you can update it inside of the if statement as so:

```
static int getNumWithMaxDivisors(int[] numbers) {
    int currentMaxDivisors = 0;
    int numWithMaxDivisors = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int numDivisors = getNumDivisors(numbers[i]);
        if (numDivisors > currentMaxDivisors) {
            currentMaxDivisors = numDivisors; //ADD THIS LINE
            numWithMaxDivisors = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return numWithMaxDivisors;
}
```

Input:

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
System.out.println(getNumWithMaxDivisors(numbers));
```

Output:

```
4
```

Side Note: You could just as well start your for loop at `i = 2` in your `getNumDivisors()` method, since every number is divisible by 1, so there is no point in checking it. This just saves you a bit of time!

Answer (score 1):

add this line of code `currentMaxDivisors = numDivisors;` inside your if-statement like so:

```
static int getNumWithMaxDivisors(int[] numbers) {
    int currentMaxDivisors = 0;
    int numWithMaxDivisors = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int numDivisors = getNumDivisors(numbers[i]);
        if (numDivisors > currentMaxDivisors) {
            currentMaxDivisors = numDivisors; //here this is missing
            numWithMaxDivisors = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return numWithMaxDivisors;
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance to print a divisors of this number ?

Comment: the value you are looking to print is in the *currentMaxDivisors* variable.So system.out that before the return statement